# Full outer Join in Django with all columns (null if not existing)

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, outer-join

Lets assume, that there are three models A, B, C in a Django app.

B and C are referencing to A in a ForeignKeyField.

Now I want to join two models of my Django app on a foreign key, with the extra condition, that every element out of C or B is displayed, if B.x = 1 or C.y = 2, 
AND (important) at least every element out of B with B.x = 1 AND every element of C with C.y=2

so that it is possible to join B and C over A with

```
A.objects.filter( Q(b__x=1) , Q(c__y=2)).distinct()
```

Unfortunately if C is not completely in B only the elements of with both conditions will be printed, but not at least every element in B.

That would require a full outer join of both tables, but I couldn't get my head around how to build a queryset for it.

I tried to concatenate both querysets like

```
a = A.objects.filter( Q(b__x=1) ) 
b = A.objects.filter( Q(c__y=2) )
c = ( a | b )
```

But in this case some desired values of B and C are missing.
Is there a way to select all the elements I want without looping "manually" over the results and add missing elements?

Comment: could django raw queries help?  django offers the option to perform your own raw queries by allowing you to write your own sql.

Comment: This would help, if there is no solution in Django itself available. Unfortunately I'm not that experienced in SQL, but I'll try to check it in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, what you want is equivalent to excluding all instances of model A where `B.x!=1` or `C.y!=2`. In that case, you could use:

```
A.objects.exclude( ~Q(b__x=1) , ~Q(c__y=2)).distinct()
```

**edit**

Which btw is equivalent to:

```
A.objects.filter( Q(b__x=1) | Q(c__y=2)).distinct()
```

and should work too.

Comment: But if there are no Elements matching C.y=2 the result set would be empty, so that not at least every Element of B matching B.x=1 gets displayed.

Comment: For some reason the join includes Elements of C with y !=2. But I ended up removing them with a simple for-loop.